# Format Document bug with CSS Media Queries in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: css, visual-studio-2012

So this:

```
@media(min-width:768px)
{
    .mini-logo
    {
       display: block;
       float: left;
       padding-top: 15px;
    }

}
```

Becomes this:

```
@media(min-width:768px)
{
    .mini-logo;

{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

}
```

In Visual Studio 2012 when Formatting Document (CTRL+K,CTRL+D)

I have this update already: http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads#d-visual-studio-2012-update

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just put space before open parenthesis

```
@media (min-width:768px)
```